# Multiple Vlookup with Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to understand something.

I have a first file with fruit name and numbers inside. Then a second which set up new names as a result of sum of fruit names.

Example.

```
  A     B 
Kiwi    12
Apple   3
Kiwi    14 
Banana  2
Apple   11
Orange  6 
Orange  8
Pomelo 12
```

And now I have a second table which say

Merge Fruit. Meaning now in the 3rd Tab, Kiwi also contain apple.

```
from     to  
Apple   Kiwi
```

And my third table where B is what I am trying to find as the sum of all the fruit.

```
A           B 
Kiwi       40 (sum of all Kiwi and apples)
Banana     2(there is just 2 in the first tab)
Orange     14 (6+8)
Pomelo     12
```

I know how to find all the fruit when the name don't move with a formula like

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$B$8,A1,$B$1:$B$8)
```

but I don't know how to do when the names are 'merged'. The 2 first tab will be always given and the A column of the third one too. I need to find just the column B of the last tab. Any ideas? The merge between fruits can be between 2 or more fruits, it can be 3,4 ...

Thank you

Comment: Please do not change the question after receiving an answer, it opens me up to down votes because my answer no longer works for your new criteria.  If you realize you asked the wrong question, try to modify the answer given to suit your needs, if you cannot change it on your own ask a new question and refer to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a formula like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G2,A:A,0)),SUMIF(A:A,G2,B:B),SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$3=G2)*(SUMIF(A:A,$D$2:$D$3,B:B))))
```

The Sumproduct will iterate through the second list if needed, DO NOT use full column references where I have not, it will slow down the calcs.

[image]

---

It first looks to the first table and if it exist there it does a simple SUMIFS().

If you want to look first to the second table then we would need to reverse the logic a bit:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G2,E:E,0)),SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$3=G2)*(SUMIF(A:A,$D$2:$D$3,B:B))),SUMIF(A:A,G2,B:B))
```

It will now look first for a match in the second table before going to the first.

---

To answer your new edited question, the formula gets simpler:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($E$2:$E$8=G2)*SUMIF(A:A,$D$2:$D$8,B:B))+SUMIF(A:A,G2,B:B)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you it works! Lets say not in the column 'to' its not Kiwi-apl anymore but just Kiwi, so Apple have been absorbed by Kiwi. Does the formula should still works? Tha'ts my problem actually instead of Kiwi-apl, Apple have been absorbed by Kiwi, so it should be 'from Apple to Kiwi' thats all. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No, it would look first to the first table.  I have edited the answer to reverse the logic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand your formula, that's great. I edited my question since actually its more a fruit name which absorb an other fruit and that was my real problem... Thank you!

Comment: @user6457870 see third part for the new formula.